# How does 'max_concurrency' in AWS upload/download file API work?

Tags: amazon-s3

Hi the AWS upload/download file API takes a parameter "max_concurrency", see this line of source code: https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/5d6c2906e87eb6365ef126014dc9f17c1a78a3e0/boto3/s3/transfer.py#L173 .

My question is: how does it work behind the scene?

Suppose I call upload_file(max_concurrency=50) in thread-A, and call upload_file(max_concurrency=50) in thread-B, will the entire process have concurrency=100? or 50?

I have the same question to another field called 'max_bandwidth', too.